# Como lidar com o dialeto Processing do Java?

Tags: debate, tag-específica

Veja [essa pergunta, especialmente o comentário](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/260070/101).

A linguagem usada é [Processing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Processing_(programming_language)) e não Java. Ela é um dialeto do Java.

Devemos usar a *tag* Java neste contexto? Por ser uma linguagem de nicho e muito parecida pode fazer sentido o uso de *tag* adicional para notificar a sub-comunidade.

Devemos usar [processing](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/processing) mesmo? Não seria melhor outra? Qual?

Alguma outra questão para debater?

Comment: Eu creio que deixar claro que é [tag:processing] é parte essencial para o leitor desavisado. Principalmente javeiros como eu, que só conheceram Processing devido ao SO. Quanto ao uso da tag Java, meu lado pragmático não vê grandes problemas (apenas vantagem de visibilidade), mas meu lado purista fala que não é adequado.

Comment: Penso igual, por isso abri debate, estou fazendo isso internamente :)

Answer (score 3):

Acho que devemos usar [processing](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/processing) mesmo. Esse é o nome da linguagem. 
Ela é construída em cima do Java, mas é **outra** linguagem.
Achei interessante [a discussão](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/321127/460775) no meta do SOen.

Alguns pontos citados nessa discussão que acho que deveríamos levar em conta:

> But most Processing developers never interact with that Java code.

Se a maior parte dos programadores que usam Processing nunca interagem com um código Java, porque motivo deveríamos relacionar as duas linguagens no nome da tag?

Por que criar confusão a um desavisado que lê a tag [java](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java) na pergunta? Ele vai acabar respondendo com um código Java que não é útil. Ou conforme aconteceu no SOen, as pessoas pedindo informações que só existem ou precisam ser explícitas no Java.

> comenters and askers (...) treat questions as purely Java questions. Asking to see a main() function that Processing simply doesn't use. Asking the OP to provide definitions for functions that are internal to Processing. Saying that the syntax is invalid, even though it's perfectly valid Processing syntax.

tldr: A tag devia ser "processing" ou algo similar a "processing-lang". A wiki devia explicar que não se deve usar a tag Java em conjunto para evitar respostas de baixa qualidade.