# Para que serve a tag java-processing?

Tags: debate, suporte, tags, tag-específica, wikis-de-tags

Por curiosidade.

O que significa a tag java-processing? Qual é o escopo dela?

Não encontrei nada na wiki da tag.

**O que seria bom ter nessa wiki?**

A tag é bem representada por suas perguntas?

Comment: https://processing.org/

Comment: Entendi. Só está faltando a wiki então. Alguém teria alguma sugestão?

Comment: Relacionado: https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/6652/como-lidar-com-o-dialeto-processing-do-java

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Parece que quando a tag foi trocada ([processing](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/processing) virou sinônimo de [java-processing](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java-processing)), o wiki se perdeu. Por sorte os moderadores têm uma espécie de achados e perdidos de tag wikis (que é bagunçado e ninguém nunca lembra de olhar).

Achei lá o wiki original, reproduzido abaixo. Fica como sugestão, podem editar à vontade lá.

---

#### Versão resumida

---

processing é uma ferramenta de programação de código aberto e ambiente de desenvolvimento integrado (IDE), baseada em Java e construída para a comunidade de artes eletrônicas com o objetivo de ensinar noções básicas de programação em um contexto visual.

---

#### Versão completa

---

Processing é uma ferramenta de programação de código aberto e ambiente de desenvolvimento integrado (IDE), baseada em [java](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java) e construída para a comunidade de artes eletrônicas com o objetivo de ensinar noções básicas de programação em um contexto visual.

Os programas em Processing são chamados de *sketches* (esboços), e contém basicamente duas partes: uma função `setup` que roda na inicialização, e uma função `loop` que é invocada repetidamente conforme a taxa de quadros definida pelo programa.

### Referências

Fonte: [Processing - Wikipédia](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Processing_%28linguagem_de_programa%C3%A7%C3%A3o%29)
 - [Site oficial](http://processing.org)
 - [Processing - Wikipédia](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Processing_%28linguagem_de_programa%C3%A7%C3%A3o%29)

Comment: Legal, vou editar lá quando estiver no PC, se ninguém o fizer antes. Valeu @bfavaretto!